# Cakephp 3 Paypal IPN not reading post data

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal, cakephp-3.0

I have integrated Paypal IPN into my Cakephp but no matter what I do, the file_get_contents('php://input') function is not reading the data coming back from the Paypal.

If I run the same code natively outside the Cakephp framework, it works perfectly.

In my error log, the last text I get says [2017-06-16 17:19 UTC] Invalid IPN: cmd=_notify-validate

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
public function jawaab()
{

    define("DEBUG", 1);
    // Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
    define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
    define("LOG_FILE", "master_error.log");
    // Read POST data
    // reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
    // issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.

    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);

    $counter = 0;

    $myPost = array();

    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2)
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }
    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    // Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
    // Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
    if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
        $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    } else {
        $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    }
    $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
    if ($ch == FALSE) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    }
    // CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

    // This is mandatory for some environments.
    //$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
        {
        if(DEBUG == true) { 
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
    } else {
            // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
            if(DEBUG == true) {
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
    }

    // Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
    // Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
    $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
    $res = trim(end($tokens));

    if ($res == "VERIFIED"){
        error_log("\r\n\r\n I AM IN -- \r\n\r\n " . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        // assign posted variables to local variables
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

       // include("dbcontroller.php");
      //  $db = new DBController();

        // check whether the payment_status is Completed
        $isPaymentCompleted = false;
        if($payment_status == "Completed") {
            $isPaymentCompleted = true;
        }
        // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        $isUniqueTxnId = false; 
        $result = $this->Payments->find('all', ['conditions' => ['txn_id = ' => '$txn_id' ]]);

        if(empty($result)) {
            $isUniqueTxnId = true;
        }   
        // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
        // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct

        if($isPaymentCompleted && $isUniqueTxnId) {


            $paymentsTable = TableRegistry::get('Payments');
            $paymnt = $paymentsTable->newEntity();

            $paymnt->booking_id = $item_number;
            $paymnt->item_name = $item_name;
            $paymnt->payment_status = $payment_status;
            $paymnt->payment_amount = $payment_amount;
            $paymnt->payment_currency = $payment_currency;
            $paymnt->txn_id = $txn_id;

            if ($paymentsTable->save($paymnt)) {
                // The $payment entity contains the id now
                $id = $paymnt->id;
            }


            if(($paymentsTable->save($paymnt)))
            {
                $bookingsTable = TableRegistry::get('Bookings');
                $bookngs = $bookingsTable->get($item_number); // Return article with id 12

                $bookngs->status = 1;
                $bookingsTable->save($bookngs);
            }   
           // else
            //{
            //    $errori = $qry;
            //}
        }
        else
        {

            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "\r\n\r\n Something is not true - $isPaymentCompleted -- $isUniqueTxnId -- \r\n\r\n " . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        // process payment and mark item as paid.


        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req $errori". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        error_log("\r\n\r\n $res $counter \r\n\r\n". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        $counter = $counter+1;  
    } 
    if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
        // log for manual investigation
        // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req  $errori" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: can you show the `debug()` of $req and the `debug()` of `$raw_post_data`. Also, in cake 3 it is best to read input data via `$this->request->input()` [Cake Book on Input](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#put-patch-or-delete-data)

Comment: @Kelvin I have tried all of them and they do not return any data.

Comment: can you try posting to the same endpoint using postman? It might be that your routes are not properly setup. Send a post request from postman or curl to your endpoint and see if you get any data. If not, you know your routes need to be fixed. You can also try simply requesting the route in your browser and put an exist statement in your function to see if the function is even getting called.